# Specify multiple data log files (IIS and Tomcat) in one profile for WebTrends

Tags: tomcat, iis, logging, analytics, webtrends

Is it possible in WebTrends to specify multiple data log files for one profile? And how can this be done? Or, is only one data log file per WebTrend profile permitted?

I want to take an IIS log file and a Tomcat log file and combine them into one profile. If there is no means for WebTrends to use more than one file per profile, than I imagine a custom report would have to be created which may employ multiple profiles, yes?

Thank you.

**Update**

Please let me explain why this question was raised, so you may understand. I have a server configuration where IIS is the front-end web server, Tomcat is the back-end web server, and an AJP Connector hooks into Tomcat from IIS.

IIS --> AJP --> Tomcat

Up until this point, we were using standard IIS logging and using that log for Web Trends and all was right in the world.

Then, an F5 load balancer was placed in front of this server. The load balancer passes the X-Forwarded-For header to record the client IP address. I was able to add this header to the standard IIS logs, but the problem is there's no way in standard IIS logging to swap the c-ip column and X-Forwarded-For column. The c-ip column shows the LB IP address, but the idea is that column should still show the client IP Address. Hence, the attempt to swap c-ip and X-Forwarded-For column data.

Why swap the columns? The Web Trend administrator was having difficulty uploading the IIS standard log to Web Trends. He spoke to someone at Web Trends. Apparently, Web Trends told him that in order for the log to be accepted, the client IP address must appear in the c-ip column. It won't accept the client IP address in the X-Forwarded-For column.

This individual who is in charge of Web Trend administration couldn't find an answer on how to swap the columns using Web Trends. The solution, at the moment, is an offline script which swaps the columns such that it is prepared to be inputted into Web Trends.

So I'm looking for a better way.

If there's a way to upload to Web Trends an IIS standard log with a custom header appended to it (X-Forwarded-For) such that the custom header contains the value of the client IP address and not the c-ip column, I'm all ears.

I tried my hand at IIS Advanced Logging and was able to manipulate the columns such that X-Forwarded-For swapped with c-ip. Great. Now I got the IP Address data in the appropriate column and the column order is exactly as it was in standard logging. The problem now is that IIS Advanced Logging is recording the page hit as the redirector DLL file that facilitates hooking up IIS to Tomcat. So, any page accessed in IIS will show up correctly in the log. But for any page that is hosted by Tomcat, the logs will record it as this redirector DLL file.

I enabled IIS debugging to see what modules/filters were firing and I saw that the Advanced Logging fires, then the URL changed from, i.e. mypage.jsp to redirector.dll, and then Advanced Logging fires again. I tried to set it up such that IIS Advanced Logging was the first module that fires before everything else but the results were the same. I don't think IIS Advanced Logging was designed in mind with hooking into JSP/Java servlet containers such as Tomcat.

The only other IIS solution I can see that may work is creating a custom IIS logging module. That will require much time. The other is what I proposed in the question, which is specifying web logs from IIS and Tomcat, separately, and feeding that into Web Trends.

Perhaps you might see now why I proposed the question of combining two logs into one Web Trends profile. Any insight would be most appreciated.

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 
Create a separate data source or use an existing one and add the path to the additional log/s. 
If you create a separate/new data source be sure to edit the profile and assign the new/added data source to the profile and save it.

However...
This is an extremely unusual configuration. I'd be suspect of the business value for combining these two disparate sources of data.

Best Regards
Wayne Denman
Webtrends
Technical Services Senior Manager (EMEA)

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback and help! I'll update my question to provide you insight into why I asked if such a configuration is possible. :)